# SQL Column exists but not visible and can't select

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema

Both existing and non-existing column in SQL Server.

I am currently using SQL Server 2017 and have a column "EnableStartEndTimes" in a table "tblReport". When trying to do a select on the column in the table, it says it doesn't exist.

But when trying to add the column to the table, it says it does exist. Via my C# code, the column does not exists.

Running the following two queries in succession, within the same query window (singular database is selected):

select EnableStartEndTimes from tblReport
alter table tblReport add EnableStartEndTimes bit null

Gives the following results:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Invalid column name
> 'EnableStartEndTimes'.
>
> Completion time: 2021-03-10T09:33:47.0011192+02:00

and

> Msg 2705, Level 16, State 6, Line 9 Column names in each table must be
> unique. Column name 'EnableStartEndTimes' in table 'tblReport' is
> specified more than once.
>
> Completion time: 2021-03-10T09:33:56.6904942+02:00

Running:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblReport'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'EnableStartEndTimes'
```

Returns no results.

Neither does:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'EnableStartEndTimes'
```

There is also no EnableStartEndTimes, upper or lower case visible in the designer.

A few points to note:

- The queries are run in the same query window. Thus the same database remains selected.
- Opening and closing SQL makes no difference.
- The column is not visible in the tables design view either.
- Upper has been removed, no difference in the result.

So my assumption is there is a reference to the column (potentially created incorrectly before?) somewhere in system tables. I am unable to find any reference to "EnableStartEndTimes" anywhere though?

Comment: If you have case sensitivity enabled, your query `where upper(TABLE_NAME) = 'tblReport'...` won't return a thing... `upper` turns everything to upper case...

Comment: 2 things, ensure you are using the exact same database in all cases... this question gets asked a lot, and many times the connections are to either different servers or different databases. Also ensure you are using the same default schema in all cases. Its definitely something along those lines... columns don't magically appear/disappear.

Comment: Refresh Intellisense? Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh

Comment: Updated accordingly. Would it be possible for different schemas to be used within the same query window? The only difference is its a select vs alter.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below and check for any clashes between schemas or other duplication.

```
select Schema_Name(t.schema_id) Schema, t.[name]
from sys.columns c join sys.tables t on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.name='EnableStartEndTimes'
```

Comment: Running the above returns no records for a column named EnableStartEndTimes? Which is part of the problem.

Comment: Have you run dbcc checkdb lately? Might be worth checking for any corruption.